# How to remove "warning Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in php?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I want to get distinct values from database in php but i got this warning

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

How i remove this warning?
here is my code:

```
$startdate1=date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST['registration_opens_date']));
$enddate1=date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST['registration_ends_date']));
$startdate1  = strtotime($startdate1 ); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp  
$enddate1  = strtotime($enddate1 ); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp  
$dates=array();
// Loop from the start date to end date and output all dates in between  
for ($i = $startdate1; $i <= $enddate1 ; $i += 86400) {
    $dates[$i]=date("m-d-Y", $i);
}
$strQuery="select Distinct DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%c-%d-%Y') as transaction_date,sum(amount)as Amount from transactions where transaction_date BETWEEN '".$startdate1."' AND '".$enddate1."' group by  DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%c-%d-%Y')";
$result = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($strQuery) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
while($rs=$result->fetch_assoc ()){
    $res[]=$rs;
}
$strXML = "<chart caption='Reports of transactions' showValues='0' xAxisName='Date' yAxisName='Amount' useRoundEdges='1' palette='3'>";
for ($i = $startdate1; $i <= $enddate1 ; $i += 86400) {
    foreach($res as $r){
        if($r['transaction_date']==$dates[$i]){
            $substrXML  .= "<set label='" .$r['transaction_date'] ."' value='" .$r['Amount'] ."' />";
            break;
        }
        else {
            $substrXML = "<set label='".$dates[$i]."' value='0'/>";
        }
    }
    $strXML .=$substrXML;
}
```

Comment: Test if $res is set, and is an array before the loop

Comment: The error means what you pass to `foreach` is **not** an array. In this case, when the loop iterates for the first time, the array isn't defined yet, and that error message will be thrown. First of all, initialize an empty array using `$res = array();` before the loop. To make sure the argument is ***always*** an array, you can use [`is_array()`](http://php.net/is_array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately before the foreach add this line:

```
if(!isset($res) && ! is_array($res)) continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your variable and it's empty.

Add this before your while loop:

```
$res = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$res` is never defined. It is only ever assigned values inside your `while()` loop from your SQL query. In case the query returns a blank set of data, `$res` will be undefined and thus PHP will throw an error.

Try defining `$res` as a blank array at the start of your code:

```
$res = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate foreach trick

```
if(!empty($rows)) foreach( is_array($rows) ? $rows : array($rows) as $row) {
    // no error possible
}
```